# CUDA 4.1 problems

Tags: c++, cuda

I have just updated to the latest (release) CUDA 4.1 from 4.0, and none of my projects are working properly any more. Moreover, the problems seems erratic. What I can understand is that some pointers to device memory are remaining `NULL` after `cudaMalloc`, but this doesn't happen immediately. Nsight and the visual profiler tell me that some memory related functions (`cudaMemcpy` and the like) are returning unknown error flags. `cudaStreamQuery` is also mainly returning the not ready stream flag.

Sorry for the vagueness, but that is the gist of it. Different projects are manifesting the problem in different ways, but it is mainly the null pointers.

Anyone have an idea what gives?

**Update:** Alright, in one of the projects the Nsight Debugger is flagging an out of range memory load, but I still cannot understand why. This worked before. Moreover, the addresses that the CUDA debugger is saying I'm trying to access do not make much sense, given the code:

```
        //  Get the mask pixel, if it has been supplied.
    if (maskImage != NULL)
        maskPixel = *(static_cast<uchar*>(maskImage->imageData) + maskImage->widthStep * (int) yPosition + (int) xPosition);
```

Now, an entire warp is trying to access, according to the debugger, out of bounds addresses. But the `yPosition` and
`xPosition` values are all smaller than the mask dimensions! Furthermore, the address that all threads in this warp, except for a few, are trying to access is `0x200000002`. I cannot make sense of it.

**Update 2:** I've fixed the last problem - as expected, it was user error. Now I've got another one in a different project, and this time, I can confirm that it's CUDA 4.1 related. `cudaBindTexture2D()` is raising an `invalid argument` error where it was not before. I guess this is a texture alignment problem?

Comment: have you updated your driver as well, the driver recommended for 4.1?

Comment: Did you try to make a cold reboot of the computer? Can you run deviceQuerey from the SDK properly?

Comment: I can run deviceQuery (the .exe) well, and it says version 4.1 in the CUDA field.

Comment: How about the number of CUDA enabled devices? I am asking this because I had the same issue when i installed 4.1 and i did not use the new drivers. This gave me strange issues and on issue was that deviceQuery reported a couple of thousand CUDA enabled devices. This was fixed by just installing the new drivers.

Comment: I've got two devices, and the query also returns two...

Comment: If you have tried everything above then i am all out of suggestions. Make sure that the SDK you are running is that came with 4.1. Also try a couple of SDK examples to see if you can reproduce the problem. If everything from the SDK is working fine, then i suspect that the problem is in your project. Maybe that you are linking wrong cuda libraries for your project. Make sure that the include directories and additional library dependencies are set to the correct folder.

Comment: I cannot understand what's wrong... I am linking to cudart.lib and cuda.lib. Essentially, I didn't change any settings from the 4.0 solution, except that I replaced the directories in the include and libary fields to the 4.1 ones and chose the appropriate build customisation.

Comment: Have you tried to run a couple of SDK examples as suggested? Also tried to compile a couple of SDK examples to see if they run correctly?

Comment: Yes I have, and the funny thing is that they compile and run just fine. So the problem is, as expected, me. I have narrowed down the problem a bit.

Comment: Okay good, so what you could try now is two things. First is to create a new project and use the same configuration that you use for your own project. See if you could reproduce the problem by calling a couple of  mallocs and cudamemcpy. Inspect the return value. The second thing you could try is to inspect one of the SDK exemples and use the same paths and buildrules as they are using for your project. Also try to take a look at your project folder and see if you have any cuda dll:s lying around that could be for the old cuda version. Could you tell me your inc. and lib. paths?

Comment: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\include
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.1\C\common\inc
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\lib\x64
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.1\C\common\lib\x64

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio/C++ and if you are, what version?

Comment: Okay, so in VS10. Right click on project and press Build Customization. There you should have CUDA 4.1 checked. Under project properties -> c/c++ -> general->inc.dir i have:                     %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);$(CudaToolkitIncludeDir) and for project properties -> linker -> general->lib.dir i have:            %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);$(CudaToolkitLibDir)

Comment: Yeah, they're the same here. As I posted in the update above, I have traced it the present error by Nsight to an address load (out of bounds). I'm sure this is caused by some sort of bad coding, which somehow didn't manifest itself before in 4.0, so if anyone could help me with the above, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA was failing on `cudaBindTexture2D()`, as I said above. I fixed this by making sure memory allocations were well aligned; in particular, I changed all 2D (image) allocations to use pitched memory, by replacing `cudaMalloc()` with `cudaMallocPitch()`. This takes care of alignment issues.